# VisualSearch.js, Displaying label/value in search box

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, javascript

I am using VisualSearch.js. [Demo and Library DL](http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/)

I was wondering if anyone has experience with the library and has found a way to display the 'label' instead of the 'value' when selecting from the dropdown:

[image]

results in:

[image]

using the following data structure:

```
 case 'account':
              callback([
                { value: '1-amanda', label: 'Amanda' },
                { value: '2-aron',   label: 'Aron' },
                { value: '3-eric',   label: 'Eric' },
                { value: '4-jeremy', label: 'Jeremy' },
                { value: '5-samuel', label: 'Samuel' },
                { value: '6-scott',  label: 'Scott' }
              ]);
```

I need for the select box to display 'Amanda' when 'Amanda' is clicked.  I need to keep the 'value' for use in queries so the only thing I'm trying to change is what displays in the search box.

Has anyone else found where in the code the value is pulled and put in the search box or is there an option to use the label that I am just not seeing

Comment: can you create a fiddle demonstrating the issue ?

Comment: It looks the issue was (sadly) rejected by its author https://github.com/documentcloud/visualsearch/issues/52